# How to compile separate assemblies for each class file in my class library

Tags: .net, assemblies

I have a class library with a bunch of classes and I would like to compile each of my classes into its own assembly. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible. A separate assembly is created when you compile your solution for each project that exists in Visual Studio, so you only need to create a project per class to obtain what you want.

Having said that, I am not sure that having one assembly per class is a good thing to do. Loading assemblies at run-time is expensive, and managing them at design-time requires some effort too. Would you care to elaborate on why you need such a thing?

Comment: I would like, in a single project, to compile each class into its own assembly, and not into one assembly. I don't want to create a seperate project for each class, but just have one project with multiple classes where it will produce assemblies.

Comment: The answer is simply no, then. What you want to do is not possible. Maybe the resulting single assembly can be later split into multiple assemblies using third-party tools.

Comment: Is there a way to write a bat file to do this on post-build?

Comment: The problem is not the bat file, but finding the third-party tool that would split an assembly into multiple ones.

Answer (score 3):

You might have to do some msbuild gymnastics but this might get you started on your way.

[Stack Overflow - Visual studio one project with several dlls as output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3867113/visual-studio-one-project-with-several-dlls-as-output)

Answer (score 2):

I would have to guess your real question is "can it be done automatically?"  No, you have to create a project for each assembly.  Quite a maintenance and deployment nightmare with no easily conceivable advantages.