# Class library project in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, class

I want to generate multiple DLLs from one class library project of C# based on the name spaces presented there in the C# project.

Is it possible to do so?

It will easier to add classes and save me to keep on adding project for the DLL i would require at deployment time?

This is not duplicate to project mentioned below. I don't have just small plugins to handle but System.AddIn Jobs which are big enough.

Even i want the result dll must have all the attributes a normal DLL have. For Normal DLL this information comes from Assambly file but for such dlls how to provide that information?

Thanks in Advance....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3867113/visual-studio-one-project-with-several-dlls-as-output