# how to avoid creating one project with several dlls as output?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, .net-assembly

Curretnly I am working on NopCommerce

Just want a very simple question, But not able to find exact solution
Problem is when i compile a project it generates 2 assemblies : 1. one at output path , 2. second at 
..\obj\Debug

I want to create dll only at single location , is it possible ??,what is the setting i m missing, Please tell me the link If i am missing

I am getting referene but with opposite question like this :
Visual studio one project with several dlls as output?

[Visual studio one project with several dlls as output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3867113/visual-studio-one-project-with-several-dlls-as-output)

Comment: `obj\Debug` is used as a temp and for debugging purposes. I guess you could override the behavior (not sure though), but why does it bother you?

Comment: actually ....it is referring some old source code of some old dll. i have project "Nop.Common" , it is using as reference  , i have clean up all the build and rebuild the solution again . still cant find out out where the source code iss coming.  that is the problem