# Project with multiple DLL output

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

**Problem**

I have to convert legacy code to Visual Studio 2010 projects/solution system. Is it possible to generate multiple *.dll* files from the same project? The idea would be not to create more projects then needed. After creation I could just include the header files or load it at run ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each Project will create one DLL so you would need one Project per DLL. You could have them all in the same Solution though.

Comment: So it's not possible in one project have more of them. I accept the answer!

Comment: It is now possible. please have a look at Julien answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3867113/visual-studio-one-project-with-several-dlls-as-output